# How do I make an image inside a list element clickable using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a to do list with a function to allow one to star important items.

Here is my `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>JavaScript &amp; jQuery - Chapter 7: Introducing jQuery - Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="page">
      <h2>To Do List</em><span id="counter"></span></h2>
      <form id="newItemForm">
        <input type="text" id="itemDescription" placeholder="Add description" />
        <input type="submit" id="add" value="add" />
      </form>
      <ul id="list">
      </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
    <script src="js/example.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my `example.js` which contains all the javascript functionality

```
$(function() {

  // SETUP
  var $list, $newItemForm, $newItemButton;
  var item = '';                                 // item is an empty string
  $list = $('ul');                               // Cache the unordered list
  $newItemForm = $('#newItemForm');              // Cache form to add new items
  $newItemButton = $('#newItemButton');          // Cache button to show form

  $('li').hide().each(function(index) {          // Hide list items
    $(this).delay(450 * index).fadeIn(1600);     // Then fade them in
  });

  // ITEM COUNTER
  function updateCount() {                       // Create function to update counter
    var items = $('li[class!=complete]').length; // Number of items in list
    $('#counter').text(items);                   // Added into counter circle
  }
  updateCount();                                 // Call the function

  // ADDING A NEW LIST ITEM
  $newItemForm.on('submit', function(e) {       // When a new item is submitted
    e.preventDefault();                         // Prevent form being submitted
    var text = $('input:text').val();           // Get value of text input
    if(text != ""){
        $list.append('<li>' + text + '<div class="starItemButton"><img src="images/empty-star.png" alt="empty star"/></li>');      // Add item to end of the list
        $('input:text').val('');                    // Empty the text input
        updateCount();                              // Update the count
    }
  });

  // CLICK HANDLING - USES DELEGATION ON <ul> ELEMENT
  $list.on('click', 'li', function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);               // Cache the element in a jQuery object
    var complete = $this.hasClass('complete');  // Is item complete
    if(e.target.class == "starItemButton" || $(e.target).parents(".starItemButton").size){
      item = $this.text();             // Get the text from the list item
      $this.remove();                  // Remove the list item
      $list                            // Add back to end of list as complete
        .prepend('<li class=\"starred\">' + item + '<div class="starItemButton"><img src="images/full-star.png" alt="full star"/></li>')
        .hide().fadeIn(300);
    }
    else{
        if (complete === true) {           // Check if item is complete
          $this.animate({                  // If so, animate opacity + padding
            opacity: 0.0,
            paddingLeft: '+=180'
          }, 500, 'swing', function() {    // Use callback when animation completes
            $this.remove();                // Then completely remove this item
          });
        } else {                           // Otherwise indicate it is complete
          item = $this.text();             // Get the text from the list item
          $this.remove();                  // Remove the list item
          $list                            // Add back to end of list as complete
            .append('<li class=\"complete\">' + item + '</li>')
            .hide().fadeIn(300);           // Hide it so it can be faded in
          updateCount();                   // Update the counter
        } 
    }   // End of else option
  });                                  // End of event handler
});      

                       // End of event handler
```

as you can see in my `$list.on('click'...` method, I am using the `if(e.target.class == "starItemButton" || $(e.target).parents(".starItemButton").size){` to test if the click occurred in the `starItemButton` `div`

However, this if statement seems to pass even if I click outside the div, how can I get a function that runs only if the user clicks inside the `div` with the `starItemButton` class?

Any help is greatly appreciated,

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach the handler directly to the image, instead of on the whole list item. Then you don't need to perform checks for the target, and the event would trigger only on that element.

```
$list.on('click', 'li div.starItemButton', function(e) {
    // handler
});
```

Comment: How can I access the parent list item after doing this? I'm trying `$(this).closest('li')` but its not working.

Comment: Does it not return the `li`? It should be working, as long as the `div` is a child of the `li` element.

Comment: I had forgot the parentheses around `$(this)`, thanks